# error including js files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am new to codeigniter,Am using the version of 1.7.2.i have installed freak auth in that..i want to have my another application running in that..I have copied the contents in the root folder and created view and controller..In my view book.php my js contents getting included but it is not displaying...am getting only blank screen in the browser,

i think the problem is with the script tags;my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>files/object.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>files/address.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>files/facebook.js"></script>
```

where am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem until i found out I didn't autoload url-helper. Weird thing is that several different browsers didn't output any error messages at all when looking at the html source if the errors occured inside the include statement.

Also remember to allow direct access to that dir in your .htaccess file if you use one.

Include the url-helper in your **application/config/autoload** file like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or do it on the fly in your controller

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

If .htaccess is blocking access to the file you can exclude the files dir:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|stylesheets|javascript|files)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless `/files` is an actual directory or your Files controller has a _resolve method, each of those should be a 404.

If it is a directory, then you need to confirm that you can read anything in that directory from the browser. There may be permissions issues or Apache may believe that that directory should be marked inaccessible.

On the other hand, if you have a File controller, then you are saying, `call the object.js method on the File controller`. `_resolve` lets you avoid this because it serves as a catch-all -- `call the _resolve method on the File controller and tell it that we're trying to display object.js`.

As to your organization of views and the like after that, well, I can't really help you there without knowing more about the controller and view in question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind are in order:

1) url-helper not loaded
2) htaccess is blocking treating your directory as a controller

Solutions

1) Add url in config/autoload.php
eg

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

2) Add files to the htaccess exeptions
eg

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|files)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```